# Drawing angles in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

How do I draw 2 lines that are x degrees relative to each other?

I tried polar coordinates, but that only creates a point at an angle relative to the origin.

I want to create a line that is at an angle relative to the previous point, instead of the origin.

Comment: Please be more precise about what you're struggling with, maybe with a sketch. And feel free to read the manual introduction. Something like `\draw (0,0) -- (3,5) --++ (60:2);` seems to be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the example in my comment was not well chosen since the angle is almost the same for both parts of the path ^^

Here's a simple example of how to continue a path with an angle and a length relative to the last point.

Here you draw a line from (0,0) to (5,3), then a second line from (5,3) to the point that is at 60 degrees and 2 cm from it (the grid is only here to show the coordinates).

[image: lines]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[help lines] (0,0) grid (6,5);
        \draw (0,0) -- (5,3) -- ++(60:2);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```